# RANKX returns 1 for all ISO Codes

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

```
Test Ranking2 = 

var test = Table[Slicer] 

var NumericValue =IF( CONTAINSSTRING(test, "%"), VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(test, "%", "")), IF (CONTAINSSTRING(test, "$"), VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(test, "$", "")), BLANK() )) 

return 

RANKX(FILTER(ALL(Table[IsoCode]), NumericValue), NumericValue,,ASC)
```

I want to rank ISO Code column based on value in Slicer. Slicer has both % and $ values based on selected column, so I created NumericValue variable to convert all values to type number and remove % or $ for calculation. My $ values are based on Sum of column grouped by ISO Code and % are based on Average of column grouped by ISO Code.

I tried different forms in expression field like :

1. returns 1 for all ISO Codes

```
MAXX(WinLossDataWithCountry,NumericValue)
```

2. returns different numbers with duplicate ranking but giving value 10000 and 400 same rank. So its wrong

```
SUMX(WinLossDataWithCountry,NumericValue)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample .pbix?

Comment: RANKX(ALL(Table), NumericValue,,ASC) solved the problem